# Proving the inequality with finite sums

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, summation

I would like to show the following inequality involving finite sums ($x>0$):

$$2 \left(\sum_{n=1}^k nx^n\right)^2 + \sum_{n=0}^k x^n  \sum_{n=1}^k nx^n - \sum_{n=0}^k x^n \sum_{n=1}^k n^2x^n \geq 0 $$

I thought an induction would work, but then realized what really matters is the first few terms in series. In my view, induction will be of no use. After plugging in some value for $k$, I noticed  a nice pattern. For ex: when $k=3$, first $3$ terms get cancelled. When $k=4$, first 4 terms get cancelled. However, I am unable to write things precisely. For a given $k$, the coefficients of first $k$ terms are $1,5,14,30,55...$. The hard part is actually to figure out the stuff after $k$ terms.

I was wondering if there would be another way to go about showing this. Any help/hint would be great.

---

A direct approach will definitely work. Is there a way to write these products of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{2k} c_n x^n$?.

Comment: "power series" means infinite sums. I only see finite sums above. Perhaps the "summation" tag is more suitable.

Comment: @311411 Technically, $1+x+0x^2+0x^3+\cdots$ is a power series ;)

Comment: True enough! @K.defaoite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired inequality is written as
$$2 \left(\sum_{n=0}^k nx^n\right)^2 + \sum_{n=0}^k x^n  \sum_{n=0}^k nx^n - \sum_{n=0}^k x^n \sum_{n=0}^k n^2x^n \geq 0$$
or
$$2 \sum_{n=0}^k nx^n \cdot \sum_{m=0}^k mx^m + \sum_{n=0}^k x^n  \sum_{m=0}^k mx^m - \sum_{n=0}^k x^n \sum_{m=0}^k m^2x^m \geq 0$$
or
$$\sum_{m=0}^k \sum_{n=0}^k (2nm + m - m^2)x^{m+n} \ge 0.$$

Let
$$\sum_{m=0}^k \sum_{n=0}^k (2nm + m - m^2)x^{m+n} \equiv \sum_{q=0}^{2k} c_q x^q.$$

If $0 \le q\le k$, we have
$$c_q = \sum_{m=0}^q [2(q-m)m + m - m^2] = 0.$$

If $k < q \le 2k$, we have
$$c_q = \sum_{m=q-k}^k [2(q-m)m + m - m^2] = (k+1)(q-k)(2k+1-q) \ge 0.$$

We are done.

Comment: Nice derivation. (+1)

Comment: @epi163sqrt Thank you!

Comment: In fact it seems your approach is less cumbersome than mine. :-)

Comment: @epi163sqrt A little bit simpler :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's define
$$P(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^Kx^n$$
Then
$$P'(x) =\sum_{n = 1}^K nx^{n-1}$$
$$P''(x) =\sum_{n = 1}^K n(n-1)x^{n-2}$$
The initial inequality is equal to
$$\begin{align}
&\Longleftrightarrow 2 \left(x\sum_{n=1}^K nx^{n-1}\right)^2 + \left( \sum_{n=1}^K nx^n -  \sum_{n=1}^K n^2x^n\right) \sum_{n=0}^K x^n  
\geq 0  \\
&\Longleftrightarrow 2 \left(x\sum_{n=1}^K nx^{n-1}\right)^2 - x^2\left(\sum_{n=1}^K n(n-1)x^{n-2}\right)\sum_{n=0}^K x^n  
 \geq 0  \\
&\Longleftrightarrow 2 \left(P'(x)\right)^2 - P''(x).P(x)  \geq 0  \\
&\Longleftrightarrow 2 \frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}  -\frac{P''(x)}{P'(x)}  \geq 0  \\
&\Longleftrightarrow (2 \ln(P(x))  -\ln(P'(x)))'  \geq 0  \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left(\ln\frac{P^2(x)}{P'(x)}\right) '  \geq 0  \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \ln\frac{P^2(x)}{P'(x)}  \text{: increasing function} \\
&\Longleftrightarrow  \frac{P'(x)}{P^2(x)}  \text{: decreasing function} \\
&\Longleftrightarrow  \left(-\frac{1}{P(x)}\right)'  \text{: decreasing function} \\
&\Longleftrightarrow  -\frac{1}{P(x)}  \text{: concave function} \tag{1} \\
\end{align}$$

It's easy to prove that

- $h(x):=\frac{1}{x}$ is a nonincreasing( $h'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}<0$) and concave function ($h''(x) = \frac{2}{x^3}$) for $x<0$
- $g(x):=-P(x)$ is a concave function for $x>0$

Applying the $(3.10)$, third result, at the page 84 of this [course](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) : "$f(x) = h(g(x))$ is concave if $h = \frac{1}{x}$ is concave and nonincreasing, and $g = -P(x)$ is concave ", we have that $(1)$ holds true. Q.E.D

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140270/discussion-on-answer-by-nn2-proving-the-inequality-with-finite-sums).

Answer (score 2):

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{2}&\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{n=1}^knx^n\right)^2+\sum_{n=0}^kx^n\sum_{n=1}^knx^n
-\sum_{n=0}^kx^n\sum_{n=1}^kn^2x^n}\\
&=2\left(\sum_{n=1}^knx^n\right)^2
+\sum_{n=0}^kx^n\left(\sum_{n=0}^knx^n-\sum_{n=0}^kn^2x^n\right)\tag{1}\\
&=2\left(\sum_{n=1}^knx^n\right)^2
+\left(\sum_{n=0}^kx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^kn(1-n)x^n\right)\tag{2}\\
&=2\sum_{q=0}^{2k}\left(\sum_{{m+n=q}\atop{0\leq m,n\leq k}}mn\right)x^q
+\sum_{q=0}^{2k}\left(\sum_{{m+n=q}\atop{0\leq m,n\leq k}}n(1-n)\right)x^q\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^{2k}\left(\sum_{{m+n=q}\atop{0\leq m,n\leq k}}2mn+n(1-n)\right)x^q\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^{k}\left(\sum_{n=0}^q\left(2n(q-n)+n(1-n)\right)\right)x^q}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{\qquad+\sum_{q=k+1}^{2k}\left(\sum_{n=q-k}^k\left(2n(q-n)+n(1-n)\right)\right)x^q}\tag{4}\\
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $\sum_{n=0}^kx^k$ and start indices with zero which is simply an addition of zero terms.
- In (2) we merge the inner sums.
- In (3) we apply the Cauchy product of series.
- In (4) we eliminate the index variable $m$ by substituting $m=q-n$. We also split the sum due to the restriction $0\leq m,n\leq k$.

The left-hand inner sum of (4) simplifies to
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^q}&\color{blue}{\left(2n(q-n)+n(1-n)\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^q\left((2q+1)n-3n^2\right)\\
&=(2q+1)\sum_{n=0}^qn-3\sum_{n=0}^qn^2\\
&=(2q+1)\frac{q(q+1)}{2}-3\,\frac{q(q+1)(2q+1)}{6}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=0}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
The right-hand inner sum of (4) simplifies to
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=q-k}^k}&\color{blue}{\left(2n(q-n)+n(1-n)\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=q-k}^k\left((2q+1)n-3n^2\right)\\
&=(2q+1)\frac{1}{2}\,k(k+1)-3\frac{1}{6}\,k(k+1)(2k+1)\\
&\qquad-(2q+1)\frac{1}{2}\,(q-k-1)(q-k)+3\frac{1}{6}\,(q-k-1)(q-k)(2q-2k-1)\\
&\,\,\qquad\color{blue}{=(k+1)\left(3kq-2k^2-q^2+q-k\right)}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

> From (1) and (4) to (6) we finally derive
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{2}&\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{n=1}^knx^n\right)^2+\sum_{n=0}^kx^n\sum_{n=1}^knx^n
> -\sum_{n=0}^kx^n\sum_{n=1}^kn^2x^n}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=(k+1)\sum_{q=k+1}^{2k}\left(3kq-2k^2-q^2+q-k\right)x^q}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>
> A plausibility check for small values $k$ verifies (7) with somewhat help from Wolfram Alpha.
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{c|c}
> k&\mathrm{polynomial}\\
> \hline
> 1&2x^2\\
> 2&3\left(2x^3+2x^4\right)\\
> 3&4\left(3x^4+4x^5+3x^5\right)\\
> 4&5\left(4x^5+6x^6+6x^7+5x^8\right)\\
> 5&6\left(5x^6+8x^7+9x^8+8x^9+5x^{10}\right)\\
> 6&7\left(6x^7+10x^8+12x^9+12x^{10}+10x^{11}+6x^{12}\right)\\
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}

Comment: This is an amazing answer I have never heard of the Cauchy product of series +1

Comment: @KamalSaleh: Thanks for your nice comment. I've added a reference to it.

Comment: Excellent!. However, I doubt the whole thing is equal to 0. Maybe it is $\geq 0$ (at some point when applying Cauchy product, we get the inequality not equality)?

Comment: It could be step (3), we have $\geq$ not equality.

Comment: @Jane: We also have equality in step (3). The calculation shows the left-hand side of the inequaliy is $0$.

Comment: @epi163sqrt  Shouldn't the index of the inner sum run from $n=2$ to $q$. This will give something non-zero. I was puzzled because when I checked the left hand side of the inequality for some values of $k=3,4,5...$ , I definitely got something non-zero.

Comment: @Jane: From (1) we see indices can start with $n=0$ since here were are adding zeros only. But, I will check the calculation thoroughly after work.